# Why does my disableButtons method not work?

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a schoolproject for C# and I am making Tic Tac Toe.
I have a little problem though..

My code used to work perfectly fine untill I build in a scoreboard.

I think the scoreboard is overruling the disableButtons.. Before I added the scoreboard it worked perfectly fine..

Can someone look at my code and tell me what's wrong?

**It's supposed to work like this:**

Play, if there is a winner, disable buttons. Please help me out!

**Edit:** I don't know why my namespace is in this textfield..

```
namespace Tic_Tac_Toe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool turn = true; //true = x en false = o
        int turn_count = 0;
        static String player1, player2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void setPlayerName(String n1, String n2)
        {
            player1 = n1;
            player2 = n2;
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Gemaakt door Luca Fraser", "About");
        }

        private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            if (turn)
                b.Text = "X";
            else
                b.Text = "O";

            turn = !turn;
            b.Enabled = false;
            turn_count++;
            checkForWinner();

            if (turn_count % 2 == 0)
            {
                lblTurn.Text = player1 + " is aan de beurt";
            }
            else
            {
                lblTurn.Text = player2 + " is aan de beurt";
            }
        }

        private void checkForWinner()
        {
            bool thereIsWinner = false;

            //Horizontaal checken
            if((btnA1.Text == btnA2.Text) && (btnA2.Text == btnA3.Text) && (!btnA1.Enabled))
                thereIsWinner = true;
            else  if((btnB1.Text == btnB2.Text) && (btnB2.Text == btnB3.Text) && (!btnB1.Enabled))
                thereIsWinner = true;
            else if((btnC1.Text == btnC2.Text) && (btnC2.Text == btnC3.Text) && (!btnC1.Enabled))
                thereIsWinner = true;

            //Verticaal checken
            if ((btnA1.Text == btnB1.Text) && (btnB1.Text == btnC1.Text) && (!btnA1.Enabled))
                thereIsWinner = true;
            else if ((btnA2.Text == btnB2.Text) && (btnB2.Text == btnC2.Text) && (!btnA2.Enabled))
                thereIsWinner = true;
            else if ((btnA3.Text == btnB3.Text) && (btnB3.Text == btnC3.Text) && (!btnA3.Enabled))
                thereIsWinner = true;

            //Diagonaal checken
            if ((btnA1.Text == btnB2.Text) && (btnB2.Text == btnC3.Text) && (!btnA1.Enabled))
                thereIsWinner = true;
            else if ((btnA3.Text == btnB2.Text) && (btnB2.Text == btnC1.Text) && (!btnC1.Enabled))
                thereIsWinner = true;


            if (thereIsWinner)
            {
                disableButtons();

                String winner = "";
                if (turn)
                {
                    winner = player2;
                    lblO.Text = (Int32.Parse(lblO.Text) + 1).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    winner = player1;
                    lblX.Text = (Int32.Parse(lblX.Text) + 1).ToString();
                }
                MessageBox.Show(winner + " wins!");
            }
            else
            {
                if (turn_count == 9)
                {
                    lblDraw.Text = (Int32.Parse(lblDraw.Text) + 1).ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("It's a draw!");
                }
            }

        }

        private void disableButtons()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Control c in Controls)
                {
                    Button b = (Button)c;
                    b.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            turn = true;
            turn_count = 0;

                foreach (Control c in Controls)
                {
                    try
            {
                        Button b = (Button)c;
                        b.Enabled = true;
                        b.Text = "";
                }
                    catch { }
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 formtwo = new Form2();
            formtwo.ShowDialog();
            lblXcount.Text = player1;
            lblOcount.Text = player2;
            lblTurn.Text = player1 + " is aan de beurt";
        }

        private void mouse_enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            if (b.Enabled)
            {
                if (turn)
                {
                    b.Text = "X";
                }
                else
                    b.Text = "O";
            }
        }

        private void mouse_leave(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {
             Button b = (Button)sender;
             if (b.Enabled)
            {
                b.Text = "";
            }

        }

        private void resetWinCountToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblO.Text = "0";
            lblX.Text = "0";
            lblDraw.Text = "0";
        }

        private void lblOcount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblOcount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
private void disableButtons()
{
    try
    {

        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            Button b = (Button)c;
            b.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

When you iterate over a control that is not a Button, you have an exception and the loop ends.

You can try with this:

```
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        Button b = c as Button;
        if(b != null)
            b.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Or, you can add Linq: Controls.OfType<Button>() and not to deal with exceptions..

Answer (score 2):

Your existing code tries to parse every control to `Button`, if it fails and throws exception. You catch it and nothing happens.

Try this code and get only `Button`s to disable:

```
foreach (Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    btn.Enabled = false;
}
```

**A suggestion:** Comment the `catch` block code while you're developing, because its easy to debug when and where exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void disableButtons()
{
    try
    {

        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {

            Button b = c as Button;
            if(b != null)
                b.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        Console.Writeline(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

You need to check if the control is a button otherwise you will cause an exception to be thrown.

This is a prime example about why it is a **BAD** idea to swallow exceptions. If you had reported or logged the exception the problem would have been apparent.